# Can a dual national fly if one of the passports expires soon?

Tags: usa, esta, dual-nationality, new-zealand-citizens, taiwanese-citizens

I'm a dual national and have passports from both New Zealand and Taiwan. I live in Singapore and have a residence permit. The NZ passport will expire in less than 6 months and I am supposed to fly to the US. My Taiwan passport is still valid.

How can I fly to the US?

1. Can I book the flight with NZ passport and enter the US using TW passport under the Visa Waiver Program?
2. Must I renew NZ passport and just it to travel?

With the first, will I be allowed to board?

Comment: Why can you not do it all using your Taiwanese passport?

Comment: Why are you looking to complicate matters unnecessarily when you can do everything on the Taiwanese passport?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can book your ticket with the New Zealand passport and use the Taiwan passport to enter the US.  You could also book the ticket with the Taiwan passport and use the Taiwan passport to enter the US, which is likely to be simpler, as the airline won't get confused by your having two passports (I've never known an airline to be confused by that, but it's possible).

Also, because New Zealand is a member of the ["six month club,"](https://www.cbp.gov/document/bulletins/six-month-club-update) you can use the New Zealand passport to enter the US even within six months of its expiration, as long as you will leave the US before it expires.

(Taiwan is also a member of the six-month club.)